# Como formatar um objeto no output do Terraform?

Tags: cloud

Estou utilizando o **Terraform** para subir minha infra no **Linode**, tudo corre muito bem, porém, não estou conseguindo formatar o *output* da forma que gostaria. Meu Output Variables está assim:

```
output "info" {
  value = {
    for vm in linode_instance.vm:
    vm.label => vm.ip_address
  }
}
```

O código acima me proporciona uma saída conforme pode ser observado abaixo:

```
info = {
  "jenkins-master" = "74.272.12.15"
  "jenkins-slave" = "50.163.31.24"
}
```

Porém gostaria de algo próximo a isso:

```
info = [{
  "label" = "jenkins-master"
  "ip"    = "74.272.12.15"
},{
 "label" = "jenkins-slave"
  "ip"   = "50.163.31.24"
}]
```

O Terraform oferece recursos que permita formatar a saída desta forma? Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver ao fazer com que o for crie quantos objetos necessários dentro da lista/array. Código:

```
output "info" {
  value = [for vm in linode_instance.vm : {
    label = vm.label
    ip    = vm.ip_address
  }]
}
```